# How to convert Javascript string to octet/character array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, pack

I would like to know how to convert a normal Javascript string into an array of octets/characters. Like you would do with a classic C unsigned char array. I am using the Struct/JSPack library and need to extract/unpack some values from data coming in a string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [String.charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

```
var str = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
var result = [];
for(var i = 0, length = str.length; i < length; i++) {
    var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
    // Since charCodeAt returns between 0~65536, simply save every character as 2-bytes
    result.push(code & 0xff00, code & 0xff);
}
alert(result);
```

Comment: Heya! Cool, but here's the thing, we should have values between 0 to 255. I'm trying to make this compatible with the code at http://code.google.com/p/jspack/source/browse/trunk

Comment: Updated the answer to save every character in 2-bytes.